# jQuery Attaching a event to another event

Tags: jquery

Specifically I'm looking to insert a mouse out event after a click. So suppose you have the following:

```
<div id="container">
 <a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

The behavior I'd want is after every "a#link" click, I want to insert a mouse out event on the "id#container" div -- basically only fire the mouse out event if there was a click. Is there a way to bind the two events and setup some kind of if checking variable?

Comment: Do you mean after a click, always forever fire a mouseout event whenever the mouse leaves the link? Or do you mean fire it only once? Or do you mean execute the JavaScript you put in the mouseout event directly after a click?

Comment: Do you want to trigger the event, or just the handler for that event?

Comment: Trigger the event, kind of. Since the link is inside of the div, I would want the mouseout event to become active only ONCE if the click event on the link is triggered.

Comment: I reread the question, and my understanding now is something similar to g.d.d.c's answer.

Comment: @Gee - So you don't want to trigger the event, you want to actually attach a handler for when the `mouseout` actually occurs later?

Comment: I probably could have gave a better example, but think of their being two links in the div, one called active and one called inactive, if inactive is clicked, once you mouseout of the parent div, a function is triggered. Otherwise the mouseout should never trigger a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get close to what you describe:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().one('mouseleave', function () {
      // Whatever you want to happen on mouse out here.
    });
  });
});
```

That way the event only fires one time as the mouse leaves, but only if they clicked the link.

Comment: I'm not sure why I assumed it wouldn't work this way but if it does, I'll give you the check.

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't seem to work, the mouseout event on the parent div is fired immediately on without actually leaving the div. Weird. Tested with a alert('debug');

Comment: So you click and it immediately triggers the mouseout?  You might try mouseleave instead.  I'll adjust the answer to reflect.  This is how I normally bind events within other events, so the structure should be valid.  I don't know that I can explain the instant firing.

Comment: Never mind, switched out mouseout for mouseleave and it's working now. Thanks for waking me up! Extended browsing instead of working makes you a zombie!

Comment: Opps, just missed your last comment but I got it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#link').click(function(){
     $('#container').mouseout();
});
```

Comment: that would permanently bind the mouseout, so that future mouseouts would fire even if there hadn't been another click. You would need to have the mouseout handler unbind itself, or use `.one()` as g.d.d.c does above.

Comment: Actually, this would trigger a mouseout that doesn't yet exist. No worries, since this was one of the interpretations my mind jumped to when I first read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

$('#link').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().mouseout(function() {
  }
});